# Make every odd row different color than even row - Angular and CSS

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to make every other row different color. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, as it looks like it should work, but it colors me EVERY row with grey.

I am using angular, and I have parent and child component
In my parent component I pass the data to the child component.

HTML is

```
 <div class="list-view">
      <div *ngFor="let event of allEvents">
        <app-event-item
          [eventsList]="event"
        ></app-event-item>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And my CSS code of parent component

```
 .list-view {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
```

Now in child component I get multiple arrays of event with data, which i passed to child component and loop through data with *ngFor

In html then I just display the rows of data.

HTML code of child component:

```
  <div class="list-view">
    <img [src]="imageUrl" />
    <div class="about">
      <h4>
        <a>{{ eventsList.title }}</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
      <p>{{ eventsList.date }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="count">
      <p>{{ eventsList.count }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css code in CHILD component

```
 .list-view {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 300px 45% 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;

    &:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #F9F9F9;
    }

    img {
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      border-radius: 0.75rem;
    }

    .about-event {
      padding-left: 1rem;
    }
  }
```

It makes every row color #F9F9F9.

Comment: your code working fine

Comment: I think you're using sass, avec you recompiled it after your modification ?

Comment: Yes, I compiled it. I don't know why it colors every line for me.. haha

Comment: provide a full demo please

Comment: check now working fine https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/gxvsycL4/1/

Comment: I updated my question with more info about my parent and child component. I am using Angular

Comment: You are asking it to color every odd list-view element. If you want it to color the odd children of list-view element you need to select with something like > *:nth-child(odd). However, there may be some confusion about how many children there are. The grid seems to set for 4 but there are in fact only 3 direct children. Perhaps you could clarify exactly what you want.

Comment: I tried with > *:nth-child(odd) and it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Quote: _"Perhaps you could clarify exactly what you want."_ - please _do_.

Comment: I want to color every other row in my list. Exactly like this https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/gxvsycL4/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an Angular aproach:

```
<div class="list-view">
      <div *ngFor="let event of allEvents;let odd=odd" 
             [style.background-color]="odd?'red':null">
        <app-event-item
          [eventsList]="event"
        ></app-event-item>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this approach works, I just changed it to [ngStyle] like:
         [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': odd ? '#f9f9f9' : null }"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like -

```
.list-view {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 300px 45% 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;

    &:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #F9F9F9; 
    }

    img {
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      border-radius: 0.75rem;
    }

    .about-event {
      padding-left: 1rem;
    }
  }
```

You missed a curly bracket, I think.

Comment: I don't know, it compiles without error